# How to create a shallow submodule?

Tags: c, linux, git, git-submodules

I'm trying to setup the Linux kernel as a submodule of a project. It needs to be shallow (or more correctly, I don't need the history), and it should be checked out at kernel 5.10.

I have tried this:

```
git submodule add --depth 1 --branch linux-5.10.y -- git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git thirdparty/linux
```

and this
**.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "thirdparty/linux"]
        path = thirdparty/linux
        url = git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
        branch = linux-5.10.y
        shallow = true
```

then invoke

```
git submodule update --init
```

All to no avail - once it shallow clones the HEAD of Linux repo, another time it deep clones the HEAD, another time just nothing happens.
What do I miss ?

---

It seems to do fairly the same with both git-v2.25.1 and git-v2.40.0.